# How to keep using the same thread when debugging in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Given I want to debug multi-threaded Java application in Intellij IDEA and I toggle multiple breakpoints with suspend policy = **Thread**.

When I start debugging session and I press release (F9), sometimes the debugger context switch from one thread to another.

Is there a way to stick to particular thread?

Answer (score 0):

Use the conditional breakpoint with the condition depending on the thread ID like

`Thread.currentThread().getId() == 999`.